# Inserting into a table variable from information_schema appears to retrieve nothing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008.

I am writing some T-SQL to take a list of tables which are common between two databases (essentially two copies of the same database so column names are common), truncate each table in the list in the target db and append the rows from the matching table in the source db.

As part of this I am building a list of column names to use in the ultimate SELECT statement which does the appending.

The problem is that when I attempt to insert the list of column names for the table in question into a table variable, I get nothing. I developed that section of T-SQL separately however, and it works fine in isolation.

Anything glaringly wrong ?

```
DECLARE @SourceCompany  CHAR(1)
DECLARE @TargetCompany  CHAR(1) 
DECLARE @SQL            NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @lcParmDef      NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @TableCount     INT
DECLARE @t              INT
DECLARE @ThisTable      NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @TableList      TABLE (name NVARCHAR(256), RowID INT)
DECLARE @ColumnCount    INT
DECLARE @c              INT
DECLARE @RowList        NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ThisCol        NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ColumnList     TABLE (column_name NVARCHAR(4000), id INT IDENTITY )
DECLARE @ColString      NVARCHAR(4000)

 ---------------- Set source and target companies here ----------------
SET @SourceCompany = 'Z'
SET @TargetCompany = 'X'
 ---------------- Set source and target companies here ----------------

INSERT @TableList (name, RowID) VALUES (N'stran',1), (N'sanal', 2)
SET @TableCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @t = 1

WHILE (@t <= @TableCount)

    BEGIN

        SELECT @ThisTable = name FROM @TableList WHERE RowID = @t
        SET @ThisTable = N'[dbo].[' + @ThisTable + N']'

         -- Clear target table.
        SET @SQL = N'TRUNCATE TABLE [COMP_' + @TargetCompany + N'].[dbo].[' + @ThisTable + N']'
        SET @lcParmDef = N''
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @lcParmDef

        -- Build column list for current table.
        DELETE FROM @ColumnList
        INSERT INTO @ColumnList  
            SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns
            WHERE table_name = @ThisTable 

        -- PROBLEM - this always returns zero.
        SELECT @ColumnCount = Count(*) FROM @ColumnList

        SET @c = 1
        SET @ColString = ''
        WHILE (@c <= @ColumnCount)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @ThisCol = column_name FROM @ColumnList WHERE id = @c
                SET @ColString = @ColString + '[' + @ThisCol + ']'
                IF (@c < @ColumnCount) SET @ColString = @ColString + ','
                SET @c = @c + 1
            END

        --- Just print the column string for now, ultimately I will build a SELECT statement and execute.
        PRINT @ColString

        SET @t = @t + 1

    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following changes

1. Comment this line `SET @ThisTable = N'[dbo].[' + @ThisTable + N']'`. Because in `information_schema.columns` system view table name will be just stored as `tablename` not like `[dbo].[tablename]`. Not even `[square brackets]`.
2. Add a new `variable` for schema and assign `dbo` to it.

declaring `@schema_name` variable

```
 Declare @schema_name char(3) = 'dbo'
```

3. change Insert query like this.

Add the schema name filter to the query

```
INSERT INTO @ColumnList  
SELECT column_name 
from information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = @ThisTable
  and schema_name = @schema_name
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't do it. The reason is that information.schema needs a database context to be supplied somehow, either via 'USE' or explicitly. Also in this scenario I am working with dynamic database names and you (annoyingly) can't use variables in 'USE' statements.

Comment: @AlanB You can use a dynamic database name easily. `DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME = N'model',
  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT DB_NAME();';

DECLARE @dbexec NVARCHAR(512) = @dbname + N'.sys.sp_executesql'; 

EXEC @dbexec @sql;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that the use of 'information_schema' requires a database context. Here I am working with dynamic database names held in variables, and you can't (AFAIK, annoyingly) use variables in a `USE` statement. So what I do below is build some T-SQL and execute it dynamically using `sp_executesql` with output parameters to return a string with the column names for each table being processed.

```
-- Takes a list of tables in @TableList, truncates that table in a target database and appends all rows
-- from the same table in a source database, building a column list dynamically in each case.

DECLARE @SourceCo       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @TargetCo       CHAR(1) 
DECLARE @SourceCoName   CHAR(6)
DECLARE @TargetCoName   CHAR(6)
DECLARE @SQLString      NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @TableCount     INT
DECLARE @t              INT
DECLARE @ThisTable      NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @TableList      TABLE (name NVARCHAR(256), RowID INT)
DECLARE @RowList        NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ThisCol        NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ColumnList     TABLE (column_name NVARCHAR(4000), id INT IDENTITY )
DECLARE @ColumnString   NVARCHAR(4000)

 ---------------- Set source and target companies here ----------------
SET @SourceCo = 'Z'
SET @TargetCo = 'X'
SET @SourceCoName = 'COMP_' + @SourceCo
SET @TargetCoName = 'COMP_' + @TargetCo
 ---------------- Set source and target companies here ----------------

 -- Build the list of tables to process.
INSERT @TableList (name, RowID) VALUES (N'stran',1), (N'sanal', 2)
SET @TableCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @t = 1

-- Iterate through list of tables.
WHILE (@t <= @TableCount)

    BEGIN

        SELECT @ThisTable = name FROM @TableList WHERE RowID = @t

         -- Clear relevant table in target database.
        SET @SQLString = N'TRUNCATE TABLE [' + @TargetCoName + N'].[dbo].[' + @ThisTable + N']'
        SET @ParmDefinition = N''
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition

        -- Retrieve the column list for current table. 
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
        SET @SQLString =              "DECLARE @ColumnList TABLE (column_name NVARCHAR(4000), id INT IDENTITY );"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "DECLARE @c INT;"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "DECLARE @ColumnCount INT;"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "DECLARE @ThisCol NVARCHAR(4000);"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "USE " + @SourceCoName + ";"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "INSERT INTO @ColumnList SELECT column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "     WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + @ThisTable + "' "
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "     AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo';"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "SELECT @ColumnCount = Count(*) FROM @ColumnList;"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "SET @c = 1; SET @ColStringOUT = '';"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "WHILE (@c <= @ColumnCount) "
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + " BEGIN "
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "  SELECT @ThisCol = column_name FROM @ColumnList WHERE id = @c"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "  SET @ColStringOUT = @ColStringOUT + '[' + @ThisCol + ']'"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "  IF (@c < @ColumnCount) SET @ColStringOUT = @ColStringOUT + ','"
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "   SET @c = @c + 1 "
        SET @SQLString = @SQLString + "  END"
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ColStringOUT NVARCHAR(4000) OUTPUT'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @ColStringOUT = @ColumnString OUTPUT

        --- Just print the column string for now, ultimately I will build a SELECT statement using it.
        PRINT @ColumnString

        SET @t = @t + 1

    END
```